# c# .net - authentication expiring prematurely

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, forms

I am setting up the authentication cookie in c# as persistent and with an end date of one year from now, but it expires not too long after being set. The code is below...

```
DateTime endDate = new DateTime();
endDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);

FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
                                                            username,
                                                            DateTime.Now,
                                                            endDate, 
                                                            true, 
                                                            userId.ToString(),
                                                            FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);


string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(
                       FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
                       encryptedTicket);

authCookie.Expires = endDate;

Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: When you say "not too long", how long do you mean? Have you used a tool like HttpWatch to investigate whether it is that the cookie is no longer being sent, or that forms authentication is no longer recognising it?

Comment: forms authentication doesn't recognize the person as logged in after roughly 30min. I haven't tried using HttpWatch, but I did use a view cookies add on in firefox to make sure the cookies existed and were set to the correct expiration date. 

I saw two cookies present, one being .ASPXAUTH with the correct expiration date, and another ASP.NET_SessionId with "Session" as the expiration date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out...when I was checking whether the the user was authenticated, I used the following code...

```
if (HttpContext.Current.User != null && HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
     return true;
}
```

when I removed the first check (ie HttpContext.Current.User != null) it started working. Although I don't really understand how HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated could be true when HttpContext.Current.User null.

Either way, it works now, so no issue.